# Subring of real valued functions with infinite number of $0$s

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Here is the problem: Let $R$ be a ring of real valued functions over $[0,1]$. Let $S$ be the set of functions all with an infinite number of zeroes. Determine whether or not $S$ is a subring of $R$.

I am pretty sure that $S$ is not a subring of $R$. So I'm trying to find a counterexample. For some reason, I am having trouble finding two functions that both have an infinite number of zeroes and whose sum/difference has a finite number of zeroes. Any help?

Comment: The characteristic function of the rationals could be one of them. What might another one be?

Comment: When looking for $a+b=c$ where $a,b,c$ have some interesting properties, many people make the mistake of exclusively thinking about how to pick $a$ and $b$. Sometimes, it's easier to pick $a$ and $c$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be zero on rational numbers and $1$ on irrational numbers; let $g$ be zero on irrational numbers and $1$ on rational numbers. Then consider $f+g$. Clearly $f, g$ are in $S$ but $f+g = 1$. (Note: $f$ and $g$ are not continuous, so aren't in $R$ to begin with - I think you might want to say $S$ is set of continuous functions with infinitely many zeroes)

Comment: That's really creative. Is this a known function?

Comment: Neither the ring $R$ nor the set $S$ is required to contain continuous functions. Unless I misunderstood "real-valued" functions.

Comment: Yes, it's the Dirichlet function. It's important for counterexamples in Analysis, and useful for chopping into smaller sets

Comment: Whoops I added the continuity condition